# Why is a variable declared in a local scope, and put into a vector visible outside the scope?

Tags: c++, scope

My question is in regard to the following piece of code:

```
pairVectors.push_back(new vector<CompactPair>());

for (int i = 0; i < generationVectors[0].size(); ++(i))
{
    //Find the new indices of the two symbols in this pair
    long leftIndex = ((terminalIndices)[(generationVectors[0])[i].leftSymbol]);
    long rightIndex = ((terminalIndices)[(generationVectors[0])[i].rightSymbol]);

    //Make a pair out of the indices we found, then push it to the vector
    CompactPair p(leftIndex, rightIndex);
    pairVectors[0]->push_back(p);


    //Record the index of this symbol
    if (indices[(generationVectors[0])[i].leftSymbol].empty())
    {
        indices[(generationVectors[0])[i].leftSymbol].set_empty_key(-1);
        indices[(generationVectors[0])[i].leftSymbol].set_deleted_key(-2);
    }
    ((indices)[(generationVectors[0])[i].leftSymbol])[(generationVectors[0])[i].rightSymbol] = i + terminals.size();
}
```

The CompactPair p is created using the following constructor:

```
CompactPair::CompactPair(long left, long right)
{
    leftSymbol = left;
    rightSymbol = right;
}
```

Whether or not it is being pushed onto the vector does not seem to matter, leftIndex, rightIndex, p and i all remain visible outside the scope of the loop. Can anybody explain this?

I'm using the Intel c++ 15.0 compiler with optimizations disabled.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know what you mean? Can you give an example, what you mean with *visible outside of the scope*? Is there still a variable `rightIndex` after your scope ends?

Comment: If those variables are visible outside the loop then the Intel C++ compiler has some rather large bugs in it.

Comment: Can you show code where you are observing that those variables are still visible outside of scope ?

Comment: I think the problem lies in the Visual Studio debugger. In some special circumstances it shows me all variables from inside the loop even when the loop exits. Earlier it actually kept the values from those variables and used them even though new variables with the same names were declared, but that must have been a separate bug.

Answer (score 2):

You are inserting fully constructed object in your vector so when calling `push_back`, you are effectively copying(or moving if enabled) the object to a new one which sits in the vector. The scope of this new object is then tied to the one of the vector.